# Unable to load live usb

Tags: 10.10, live-usb

I have created a bootable USB with ubuntu 10.10 with usb-creator-gtk from terminal. How ever it is not getting booted. It keeps loading in the ubuntu main screen.. Is there a way to debug this problem and find the cause?

Comment: Have you checked that USB comes before the hard drive in the boot order menu in your BIOS setup?

Comment: Please be sure you are working with a good, i mean a md5sum verified Ubuntu 10.10 iso...
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes

Comment: You could try unetbootin instead

Comment: Tried that too. No use

Comment: I have the same thing(i am working on a desktop computer), but i think that there is some motherboards that didn't support booting from the USB even if you make the USB is the first in the boot list !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had similar problem, Ubuntu hanging during install from usb 3.0 slot. After moving usd-drive to usb 2.0 everything went ok. Check, if it's your case.

usb-creator-gtk also does NOT always work as expected, try unetbootin instead (it supports a lot of distros, not only Ubuntu).

Answer (score 2):

When you boot, at the boot splash, edit the boot line (usually hit the tab key) and edit (remove) the quiet and splash options.

Answer (score 1):

At least here with 10.10 when booting it would just go to a console & not load the session.
The only way would be to type this & press enter

```
live
```

Though not sure if that's what you're seeing based on question's description

Answer (score 0):

- Is your USB key/drive booting with another computer ?
- Is legacy usb enabled in the BIOS ?
- Did you try to "Load setup defaults" in your BIOS ?

It may also help if you add your motherboard model / BIOS version.

Comment: Yes it is booting fine in another system.

Comment: And when you disable the splash and quiet options , where does it hand up or what error message are you getting ?

Comment: Can you answer the other questions about your BIOS please, there are known issues with grub and the BIOS settings